# Function is not returning table

Tags: postgresql

Data is not returned by the function even though all calculations are done and i can see the messages in the console with the information.

If tried creating a record variable to store the values and return next for each row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recompra ()
RETURNS TABLE (
anho INTEGER,
cod_cliente INTEGER,
cliente VARCHAR(255),
cantidad INTEGER,
clasificacion VARCHAR(64)
) AS $$
DECLARE
anho INTEGER;
cod_cliente INTEGER;
cliente VARCHAR(255);
cantidad INTEGER;
clasificacion VARCHAR(64);
anhos_anteriores INTEGER;
BEGIN
FOR anho IN (SELECT DISTINCT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v.fecha_factura)) as anhos 
    FROM ventas_vehiculos as v
    GROUP BY anhos 
    ORDER BY anhos ASC) LOOP
    BEGIN 
    FOR cod_cliente , cliente IN (SELECT d.cod_cliente, CONCAT(TRIM(d.nombre),' ',TRIM(d.apellido))
                              FROM clientes as d  WHERE estado_cliente <> 'Inactivo' LIMIT 10) LOOP
                -- TRAE LAS VENTAS POR ANHO
    BEGIN
    FOR cantidad IN SELECT COUNT(f.nro_factura) FROM  ventas_vehiculos as f 
                    WHERE f.cliente = cod_cliente
                    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM f.fecha_factura) =anho LOOP
                    SELECT COUNT(f.nro_factura) FROM ventas_vehiculos as f 
                    WHERE f.cliente = cod_cliente
                    AND extract(YEAR FROM f.fecha_factura) < anho INTO anhos_anteriores;

                    IF (cantidad >0 AND anhos_anteriores > 1) THEN
                            clasificacion = 'Recompra';
                    ELSIF (cantidad > 0 AND anhos_anteriores = 0) then
                        clasificacion = 'Compra';
                    ELSIF (cantidad =0) THEN
                        clasificacion = 'No compra';

                    RAISE NOTICE '% -- % -- % -- % -- % --', anho,cod_cliente,cliente,cantidad,clasificacion;
                    END IF;

                    END LOOP; --- cierra loop cantidades por anho

                END; -- cierra trae ventas por anho     

            END LOOP;   --- cierra for clientes

        END; -- cierra begin clientes

END LOOP; -- CIERRA FOR ANHOS

END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

expected output

```
year   cod_cliente nombre cantidad clasificacion 
2018   1234       Juan    12      compra
2016   3232       pedro    1      recompra
```

Comment: So what does the function return? Or what error do you get?

Comment: All those nested loops should probably be replaced with proper joins  or IN conditions. And `FOR cantidad IN SELECT COUNT(f.nro_factura) ...` looks completely wrong. The query has no group by so it returns exactly one row - "looping" over exactly one row doesn't really make sense. Maybe you should take a step back, show us the tables you have (as `create table` statements), and some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) and the result you expect.

Comment: It returns nothing, no records. what i want to do is get the purchase amount by year per customer and clasify  "first purchase" in the year it was made with first purchase, subsecuent purchases in following years as "repurchase" and if there was no purchase then "no purchase"

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with your code, I'll list those I can see right away:

- There is no `RETURN NEXT` statement in your code. You'll have to have one for every row you want to return.
- You declare local variables with the same name as the output parameters, which will lead to a name conflict. Don't do that. The return parameters in the `RETURNS TABLE` clause *already are* PL/pgSQL variables.
- You should use `:=` rather than `=` for assignment. This is the supported way and avoids confusion with the comparison operator.